# Инкремент и декремент в javascript

Tags: javascript

Выполняем такой код:

```
highFives = 0;
highFives++;
0
highFives++;
1
highFives;
2
```

Почему мы получаем 2 в конце а не 1?По идее мы получили 1 и не изменяя выводим его... Разъясните пожалуйста, я не понимаю!!!

Comment: Хорошо бы непонимание возникло при первом выводе `0`, а остальное уже должно бы быть понятно.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что пост инекремент - это когда переменная вначале отдаёт своё значение, а потом его увеличивает (упрощённо для понимания. На самом деле алгоритм чуть другой). Т.к. Тут **два** раза идёт постинкремент, то минимум два раза переменная увеличит своё значение.  После второго highFives++; оно уже примет такое значение.

---

Краткий алгоритм оператора:

```
operator++(int) {
    int temp = myValue;
    myValue = myValue + 1;
    return temp;
}
```

соответственно будет в итоге:

```
highFives = 0;
int temp = highFives;
highFives = highFives + 1; // highFives становится 1
return temp;  // но отдало значение 0
int temp2 = highFives;
highFives = highFives + 1; // highFives становится 2
return temp2;  // но отдало значение 1
```

Comment: Стало очень интересно какой же там на самом деле полный алгоритм))